# FR4/PCB electrical permitivity varing over temperature and effects on trace matching, how much does it change?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, high-speed

I have a high speed design that runs at 1.6GHz, there are also matched traces on a 12 layer board. Now I would like to know if the design will function over temperature of a -10C to 50C range and if the electrical permittivity and Dk will change and by how much.

How much does electrical permittivity or Dk change with PCB materials, is it a few percent?

I am using this material for my design...
[TU-768](https://www.pcbsky.com/uploads/tu-768-datasheet.pdf)
which the datasheet isn't really useful when it comes to temperature change.

Comment: Over what range? Do you want to include the case of heating the board beyond its Tg?

Comment: Also do you want to consider that if you heat the board you might either dry it out (evaporate moisture from it) or force it to absorb water, depending on the humidity in the environment?

Comment: Added temp range (-10C to 50C) Is water worse than temperature changes?

Comment: I would expect the changes to be quite anisotropic. Z vs. X-Y in particular, because of the glass fiber orientation.

Comment: In most general terms, either the performance you're looking for is specified in the datasheets/mfg. documentation, and you trust the manufacturer to keep it that way, or you have to establish a process to qualify the material for use in your application, and to do incoming batch testing to make sure you're still getting the material you paid for :) Materials vary a lot, even "FR-4" can differ by a factor of 2 in terms of Dk tempco depending on who you get it from. To be conservative, assume that the ballpark doesn't satisfy your requirements. Measure and sleep well, I'd say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this reference in [Microwave Journal](https://www.microwavejournal.com/blogs/1-rog-blog/post/16662-fr-4-versus-high-frequency-laminates):

> To evaluate performance variations with temperature, circuit-board materials are characterized by the thermal coefficient of dielectric constant (TCDk). It is simply a measure of how much the dielectric constant changes over a defined temperature range. For FR-4, it is typically 200 parts per million (ppm) per degree Celsius (°C) change in temperature.

200 ppm/K over a 60 K variation in temperature would give about 1.2% variation for your use case.

On the other hand, [iPCB](https://www.ipcb.com/technical/762.html), a PCB vendor, suggests it could be much worse:

> The fr4 dielectric constant changes with temperature, and the maximum change range can reach 20% in the temperature range of 0-70 degrees.

"Improved FR-4" products like N6000 can be better, [here](https://www.ieee802.org/3/ap/public/may04/goergen_01_0504.pdf)(slide 11) we have a measurement of less than 0.3% variation between 0 and 60 C.